# Quill importing in angular fails

Tags: angular, quill

I have tried following [Quill documentation](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill) to install quill in my angular (v16.1.4) project with it's dependencies, but I'm still receiving an error I don't get to handle

These are the commands I used:

```
npm install ngx-quill
npm install quill
npm install @types/quill
```

imported styles in my styles.css:

```
@import '/node_modules/quill/dist/quill.bubble.css';

body {
    background-color: #931C1C !important;
}
```

And imported QuillModule on my app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DisplayComponent } from './display/display.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './error/error.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { Home1Component } from './display/home1/home1.component';
import { Home2Component } from './display/home2/home2.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { LoginModalComponent } from './login-modal/login-modal.component';
import { ModalControlService } from './modal-control.service';
import { RegisterModalComponent } from './register-modal/register-modal.component';
import { MarineComponent } from './marine/marine.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { LoginRegisterService } from './loginRegister.service';
import { HowtostartComponent } from './display/home2/howtostart/howtostart.component';
import { HomeSelectorService } from './display/homeSelector.service';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
import { NewsComponent } from './news/news.component';
import { PiratesComponent } from './pirates/pirates.component';
import { AbilitiesComponent } from './abilities/abilities.component';
import {newsObtainerService } from './news/newsObtainer.service';
import { NewPostModalComponent } from './news/new-post-modal/new-post-modal.component';
import { QuillModule } from 'ngx-quill'



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DisplayComponent,
    ErrorComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    Home1Component,
    Home2Component,
    LoginModalComponent,
    RegisterModalComponent,
    MarineComponent,
    HowtostartComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
    NewsComponent,
    PiratesComponent,
    AbilitiesComponent,
    NewPostModalComponent,
    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    QuillModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [ModalControlService,
    LoginRegisterService, 
    HomeSelectorService,
    newsObtainerService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

At this point I already get the error when I compile the code. It's the following one:

```
ERROR
node_modules/@types/quill/node_modules/quill-delta/dist/Delta.d.ts:1:8 - error TS1259: Module '"/home/alberto.plazamontes/dev/formacion/HTTop/node_modules/@types/quill/node_modules/fast-diff/diff"' can only be default-imported using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag

1 import diff from 'fast-diff';
         ~~~~

  node_modules/@types/quill/node_modules/fast-diff/diff.d.ts:20:1
    20 export = diff;
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This module is declared with 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag.
ERROR
node_modules/ngx-quill/lib/quill-editor.component.d.ts:1:21 - error TS2614: Module '"quill"' has no exported member 'Delta'. Did you mean to use 'import Delta from "quill"' instead?

1 import QuillType, { Delta } from 'quill'
```

I also tried installing the specified quill version, but still same error. These are the versions I tried:

```
npm i quill@1
npm i types@quill@1
```